# Android app(host) button click event to invoke a flutter method

Tags: android, flutter

I've added Flutter module to existing Android project.
as per this link.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

And able to display flutter widget using Flutter createFragment as below method

```
FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
tx.replace(R.id.someContainer, Flutter.createFragment("route1"));
tx.commit();
```

Now, i want to invoke a method in Flutter module, when click on a button in Android app. When i search for it, I see about MethodChannel and EventChannel to pass data. I'm not sure how to use them in host Android app. or Is there any other way for it.

Please let me know on it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried MethodChannel to invokeMethod in Flutter module as per this link

https://proandroiddev.com/communication-between-flutter-and-native-modules-9b52c6a72dd2

It worked fine.